# Regular Expression Match Route or Path

Tags: c#, .net, regex, path, routes

I want this:

```
/pessoas/vagas/de-foo/em-bar/em-xpto
```

match with

```
^/pessoas/vagas/de-(.+)/em-(.+)/em-(.+)$
```

and not match with

```
^/pessoas/vagas/(.+)?$
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you should use `[^/]` instead of `.`

Comment: "/pessoas/vagas/([^/]+)" and "/pessoas/vagas/de-([^/]+)/em-([^/]+)/em-([^/]+)" ?????

Comment: Not sure if you need to escape the slash, but yes.

Comment: per hour worked in both!! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/iG5sU6/1)?

```
(\/pessoas\/vagas\/de-\w+\/\w+\-\w+\/\w+\-\w+)
```

Btw, you can't prevent `.` to match everything. Because, `.` matches everything, it's the reason of existence of this wildcard. `.*` would match every possible string.